# How to broadcast a message to all rancher containers behind rancher balancer?

Tags: docker, load-balancing, haproxy, broadcast, rancher

I have Rancher running a few instances of the same container image and load balancing them with the load balancer (rancher/lb-service-haproxy)

Is there a way to broadcast a message to all the instances?

In my case is a POST to a REST service but if the answer could cover a more generic use case it will be great.

Thank you